# bodyParser issue in expressjs 4.0

Tags: json, node.js, express, middleware, body-parser

I am using expressjs 4.0 for my project also I am using bodyParser.json() middleware but found that bodyParser.json() middleware works weired for 'name' key of any json body.

for eg. If I sent Post body like this

```
{"name":{"displayName": "Abc"}}
```

it parses as

```
{name: "[object Object]"}
```

not sure why it bodyParser.json() parses name key as like this, but if we rename key name to any other name other than 'name'it works perfectly.

Comment: How exactly are you posting the data?

Comment: Body: {"name":{"displayName": "Abc"}}; Content-Type: application/json; HTTP: POST

Comment: Using what client?

Comment: I am using POSTMAN REST client.

Comment: Odd, because `bodyParser.json` just calls `JSON.parse` behind the scenes....and `JSON.parse('{"name":{"displayName":"Abc"}}')` [works fine](https://repl.it/K7tG/0).

Comment: Yes that's true, I was amazed by seeing this behaviour for a particular key by bodyParser.json(), anticipating some work around.

Comment: It's not caused by `body-parser`. It's either Postman (unlikely) or something in your app that's causing it (`app.param('name', ...)`, for instance).

Comment: How are you logging to console?